# Create a link to an xml page from with in my html page

Tags: html, xml

I want to have a link to an xml page from with in my webpage

Comment: Can't search for this on Google? Should you have to post it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uh.....

```
<a href="path/to/your/file.xml">My Awesome XML File!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just link to it.

```
<a href="something.xml">About my feed</a>
```

But if you want the XML to appear similar to HTML output, then you will need to style it.

See my answer to this question from earlier.

[RSS feed display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444481/rss-feed-display/7047028#7047028)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood your question. Please rewrite your question in more detailed manner. If you need to give hyper link use the following syntax.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">click here </a>
```

or

```
<a href="newpage.xml">click here </a>
```

Comment: You need at least `//` or `http://` before `www.google.com`, otherwise it will go to the file called `www.google.com` in the same directory.

Comment: @Delan - Thanks! just forgot to add it. :-) I modified my answer.